# Creating a Tree with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a treeview with javascript. Basically, when a user clicks on a a chevron in the tree it will trigger SignalR to go and get the children, and once it has a list of children it sends them back to the client, one at a time, to be populated into the view. Sounds easy.

My problem is that when a child gets sent back, my code appends it to all children.

```
<ul class="treeview">
    <li id="1032">
        <i id="1032" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
        <a id="1032" href="#">Folder 1</a>
        <ul id="1032"></ul>
    </li>
    <li id="1018">
        <i id="1018" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
        <a id="1018" href="#">Folder 2</a>
        <ul id="1018"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the page loads, it looks like this. When the `i` element gets clicked, my javascript triggers. Everything goes according to plan, except for the last method.

```
function addChild(parentID, childID, childName) {
            jQuery('<li id="' + childID + '"><i id="' +
            childID + '" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i><a id="' +
            childID + '" href="#">' + childName + '</a><ul id="' + childID + '"></ul></li>').appendTo($("#" + parentID + " ul"));
        }
```

Folder 1 has 3 Children. What I am wanting it to come out like is this;

```
<ul class="treeview">
<li id="1032">
    <i id="1032" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <a id="1032" href="#">Folder 1</a>
    <ul id="1032">
        <li id="1057">
            <i id="1057" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="1057" href="#">Child 1</a>
            <ul id="1057"></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="4563">
            <i id="4563" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="4563" href="#">Child 2</a>
            <ul id="4563"></ul>
        </li>
        <li id="1534">
            <i id="1534" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="1534" href="#">Child 3</a>
            <ul id="1534"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="1018">
    <i id="1018" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <a id="1018" href="#">Folder 2</a>
    <ul id="1018"></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

What is actually happening is this;

```
<ul class="treeview">
<li id="1032">
    <i id="1032" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <a id="1032" href="#">Folder 1</a>
    <ul id="1032">
        <li id="1057">
            <i id="1057" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="1057" href="#">Child 1</a>
            <ul id="1057">
                <li id="4563">
                    <i id="4563" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    <a id="4563" href="#">Child 2</a>
                    <ul id="4563">
                        <li id="1534">
                            <i id="1534" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                            <a id="1534" href="#">Child 3</a>
                            <ul id="1534"></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="1534">
                    <i id="1534" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    <a id="1534" href="#">Child 3</a>
                    <ul id="1534"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="4563">
            <i id="4563" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="4563" href="#">Child 2</a>
            <ul id="4563">
                <li id="1534">
                    <i id="1534" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    <a id="1534" href="#">Child 3</a>
                    <ul id="1534"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="1534">
            <i id="1534" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
            <a id="1534" href="#">Child 3</a>
            <ul id="1534"></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="1018">
    <i id="1018" class="tree-indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
    <a id="1018" href="#">Folder 2</a>
    <ul id="1018"></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is going to be something small, I am pretty sure. I have just been looking at it for too long and my brain believes that everything is ok. This could also be due to the fact that jQuery is not strong with me.

Thanks in advance.

**TO TEST**
The data is retrieved from a signalr class. For those that would like to test it out, I have made some buttons for you.

`<button onclick="addChild(1032, 1057, 'Child 1')">Add Child 1</button>
 <button onclick="addChild(1032, 4563, 'Child 2')">Add Child 2</button>
 <button onclick="addChild(1032, 1534, 'Child 3')">Add Child 3</button>`

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: the attribute `id` of each html must be unique...

Comment: @andrepaulo I am specifying <ul> elements in my method. All the ul elements have a unique id

Comment: Add `console.log(parentID, childID, childName);` to your `addChild` function to debug. Looks like it is getting called repeatedly with the wrong `parentID`

Comment: As andrepaulo says, every element should have a unique `id` (if an `id` is present), so `<li id="4563"> <i id="4563" ...>` is incorrect html

Comment: What is `jQuery('<li id="' + childID + '"....` meant to do?

Comment: @KScandrett I have tried this. Everything is correct and the method is called once per child.

Comment: @1252748 .. it creates a new DOM element

Comment: @JohZant please provide the code before ... what trigger the method and the method ... so we can execute a scenario and see what's wrong

Comment: @KScandrett the IDs are not the problem. I have used this technique before without any issue. It would be a problem if I had multiple elements of the same type with the same id or if I was just getting elements by id. However, I have specified the element name as well as the id.

Comment: Aside from being invalid HTML, it's the reason you're getting the results you are getting.  The selector `appendTo($("#" + parentID + " ul")` says give me all elements with `#parentID` that are inside a `ul`. Every time you run it is creating more elements with the same ID below a `ul`, so it compounds. You'll at least need to change the selector

Comment: @KScandrett, to what?

Comment: Possibly `$('#'+parentID+' > ul')` or `$('ul#'+parentID)`

Comment: @andrepaulo, added some buttons to trigger the js method. The data is all retrieved from a web service and then I use signalr to send, 1 at a time, parentID, childID, childName. This hits the `addChild()` method which creates the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [K Scandrett](/users/1544886) noticed, the selector inside `appendTo` is too vague. As a result, it is appending the child node to *all* `#parentID ul`, that is all `<ul>` that are descendants of the `#parentID` node.

To fix this, you could limit the selector to immediate descendants of the parent, like this: `appendTo($('#' + parentID + ' > ul'))`. As long as the `<ul>` you are wanting is directly within the `#parentID` node, this will work.

Another idea is to target the `<ul>` that has the `#parentID`. I noticed that you are sticking the same ID on all of the elements associated with each node, so `appendTo($('ul#' + parentID))` ought to work as well.

As for using duplicate element IDs all over the place, most browsers are hardy enough to tolerate it, but you *could* just use classes...